# problem , implementing quick sort algorithm

Tags: c++

I facing problem form implementing quick_sort algorithm in c++. But these two that I code is not working. Please indicate where is my fault.

```
int partition(int a[],int low,int high)
{
    int i=low-1;
    int pivot=a[high];
    for(int j=0;j<high;j++)
    {
        i=i+1;
       if(a[j]<pivot);
       int t=a[i];
       a[i]=a[j];
       a[j]=t;
    }
    i=i+1;
     int t=a[i];
       a[i]=a[high];
       a[high]=t;
    return(i);
    
}

void quick_sort(int a[],int low,int high)
{
    if(low>=high){
        return;
    }
    int p;
    p= partition(a,low,high);
    quick_sort(a,low,p-1);
    quick_sort(a,p+1,high);
    
}
```

Comment: You should consider providing some information about the kind of problem you are facing. Not working is very general. Can you provide some output or error messages?

Answer (score 0):

1. i = low, not low - 1
2. int j = low, not 0
3. Brackets

```
if(a[j]<pivot) {
   int t=a[i];
   a[i]=a[j];
   a[j]=t;
}
```

4. remove the line `i = i + 1` after the for loop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).